# Android test automation for a phone connected to my computer using USB

Tags: android, testing, automation, monkeyrunner, seetest

We need to do test automation on Android devices connected by USB to our computer (it's a bank application and we cannot use any cloud based testing due to the Bank's security policy). We are looking at a few alternatives (monkeyRunner, SeeTest from Experitest and Robotium). Any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automated Acceptance Testing For iOS and Android Devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722097/automated-acceptance-testing-for-ios-and-android-devices)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyRunner.html). If you are using Robotium you need to have the root permisission.

Otherwise Seetest is another option which will record and playback your operations

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want. MonkeyRunner is useful if you are not going to be linking your test code to your main code. If you are planning on linking your test code to your app code then robotium is the way that you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider SeeTest from [Experitest](http://experitest.com). It comes with easy recording option and it has QTP code export (as well as Java, C# and more).